# How do I export GUI mockups to Python GUI code (e.g. wxpython)?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, pyqt, mockups

I want to take my mockups and export them to code using any python GUI library (wxpython, pyqt, etc). For example, this capability already exists for mockups->HTML/Javascript here:

http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups/community

I need a fast, easy, high level mockup tool like balsamiq, not a slow, low level tool like boa constructor.

Is there any combination of mockups/exporter tools like this for python?

Comment: I think any such tool would yield poor results. Mockups usually use absolute positioning which is rarely a good idea in the real world.

Comment: This website, for example, doesn't expand anything if I make the page wider or longer. So lots of interfaces are actually fixed positioned already.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Qt Designer`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/designer-manual.html) tool to do your mock-ups and then use the `pyuic4` command line tool to convert the `.pro` file into Python code.

Here are some references if you get stuck:

https://web.archive.org/web/20130706112923/http://diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Creating_GUI_Applications_with_PyQt_and_Qt_Designer

http://wiki.python.org/moin/JonathanGardnerPyQtTutorial

Comment: This is the only tool (QT designer) I found that can really do it. Because it's designed as GUI designer (not mockup tool) but with UI completely separate from the code, so you can use it for mockups (including populating mockups with data, which most GUI designers can't do)